# Celery redis backend not always returning result

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I'm running a celery worker such that:

```
 -------------- celery@ v3.1.23 (Cipater)
---- **** ----- 
--- * ***  * -- Linux-4.4.0-31-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
-- * - **** --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         __main__:0x7fe76cd42400
- ** ---------- .> transport:   amqp://
- ** ---------- .> results:     redis://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 4 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- 
--- ***** ----- [queues]
 -------------- .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
[tasks]
  . tasks.mytask
```

**tasks.py**:

```
@celery_app.task(bind=True, ignore_result=False)
def mytask(task):
    r = redis.StrictRedis()
    r.rpush('/task_finished', task.request.id)
    return {'result': 42}
```

When I try to run the following code, and run 2 task one after the other it works when getting the first result but fails to return the second one.

```
import celery.result
import redis

r = redis.StrictRedis()
celery_app = Celery(name="my_long_task", backend="redis://")

while True:
    _, resp = r.blpop('/task_finished')
    task_id = resp.decode('utf-8')
    task = celery.result.AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery_app)
    print(task)
    print(task.result)
```

Will return:

*First loop*:

```
[1] 990e2d04-5664-4d7c-8a5c-e9cb4ef45e24  
[2] {'result': 42}
```

*Second loop* (fails to return the result):

```
[3] 8463cc46-0884-4bf7-b838-f0614f74b271  
[4] {}
```

However if I instantiate `celery_app = Celery(name="my_long_task", backend="redis://")` in the `while` loop it will work each time.
What is wrong with not reinstantiating `celery_app` ? What am I missing ?

**Edit:**

Waiting a bit for the result (in case of latency) won't work too

```
while True:
    _, resp = r.blpop('/task_finished')
    task_id = resp.decode('utf-8')
    for i in range(0, 20):
        # Won't work because I need to re instantiate celery_app
        task = celery.result.AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery_app)
        print(task.result)
        time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have a race condition.** This is what happens:

1. The loop arrives at `_, resp = r.blpop('/task_finished')` and blocks there.
2. The task executes `r.rpush('/task_finished', task.request.id)`
3. The loop unblocks, executes `task = celery.result.AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery_app)` and gets an empty result because the task has not yet recorded its result to the database.

There may be a way do the `r.rpush` *after* celery has committed the results to the backend. Perhaps creating a custom class derived from `Task` would do it. But that's not something I've tried.

However, you could certainly modify your code to store the results *together* with the task id. Something like:

```
r.rpush('/task_finished', json.dumps({ "task_id": task.request.id, "result": 42 }))
```

I've used a JSON serialization for the sake of illustration. You can use whatever scheme you want. On reading:

```
_, resp = r.blpop('/task_finished')
resp = json.loads(resp)
```

With this, you might want to change `ignore_result=False` to `ignore_result=True`.

Comment: Even with a `for loop` and `sleep` around `task = celery.result.AsyncResult(task_id, app=celery_app)`, if I do not re-instantiate the `celery_app` it won't work (I tried to wait for 10sec).
I do agree that managing the result myself would be easier but I try to understand the mechanism behind this problem